# Looking for a good tool for repeat masking in long sequences

Tags: repeat-elements, repeatmasker, repeat

The [repeat masker site](http://www.repeatmasker.org/cgi-bin/WEBRepeatMasker) has a size limit of 90kb. 
Where can I mask repeats in a 500kb sequence?

Ideally, I need a thorough repeat masking of known and de-novo found repeats of various complexity. I am working on Windows but can access Unix too.

Answer (score 4):

[RepeatMasker](http://www.repeatmasker.org/RMDownload.html) can downloaded an run locally. There's then no size limit, though do note that it's quite slow for mammalian-sized sequences (you'll want to split it into chunks and run in parallel in such cases). For a small 500kb sequence that won't pose an issue.

Answer (score 3):

[RepeatFinder](http://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/RepeatFinder/) may suffice by Volfovsky et al. (2001) and is available for download.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://meme-suite.org/doc/glam2_tut.html, here's a few tools that do various repeat masking tasks.

> These tools mask various kinds of repeats: [Repeatmasker](http://www.repeatmasker.org/), [Censor](http://www.girinst.org/censor/), [seg/pseg/nseg](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/seg/), [DUST](http://meme-suite.org/doc/dust.html),
>       [XNU](http://meme-suite.org/doc/purge.html), [DSR](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/106652703321825955), [GBA](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/22/24/2980/208627).

Censor, seg/pseg/nseg, dust, DSR all have locally available applications. DSR, GBA, and CAST are algorithms for repeat masking.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this python program to mask elements -

```
dna = input("Please enter the DNA sequence or chromosome whose repetitive elements need to be masked:")
repele = ["aaaa", "tttt", "cccc", "gggg"]
counter=0
str1=str(dna)
for i in repele:
    str1 = str1.replace(repele[counter], "x")
    counter=counter+1
print(str1)
```